# Excel - sum values based on distinct value in another column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following structure in an Excel worksheet:

```
ARTICLE     VALUE
-------     -----
   A         300
   B         100
   A         300
   C         300
   D         200
   A         300
```

I can always expect that the value for a similar article will be the same. Therefore, the value of A will always be 300. However, other articles could very well have a similar value as a previous article. Hence, C also has a value of 300.

In this case, I am trying to find the sum of unique articles, but only once in case of duplicates. So, in the above example, I need the sum as A (only once), B, C and D - which comes to 300 + 100 + 300 + 200 = 900

I found a COUNTIF formula but this only sums articles which do not have any duplicates (i.e. B, C and D)

```
{=SUM(IF(COUNTIF(A:A, A:A) = 1, B:B, 0))}
```

Am I barking up the wrong tree with COUNTIFs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were close, and `COUNTIF` is the right way to go. Try this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(B1:B6/COUNTIF(A1:A6,A1:A6))
```

I replaced `SUM` with `SUMPRODUCT` so that you don't have to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

---

[image]

Comment: That is perfect! A question on array formulas though - Is there a performance hit from either the array formula or SUMPRODUCT in case of many records?

Comment: @dreadnought303: There's not much difference between the two as long as you don't use full column refences (i.e. `A:A`). `SUMPRODUCT` will intelligently find the end of your data and stop there, whereas the CSE array formula will force calculate the whole column.

Comment: Okay, I tried the formula on the complete column and it gives a divide by zero error. So I guess this works only for non-empty columns. Is there a way that this can be generalized for a complete column (also excluding the first row as a header row)?

Comment: @dreadnought303, that can be avoided - I'll update the solution slightly

Comment: @dreadnought303, try this CSE for now: `=SUM(IFERROR(B1:B7/COUNTIF(A1:A7,A1:A7),0))`

Comment: Okay, got it to work, but in a slightly roundabout way. In a separate cell, I found the last non-empty row using the formula `=ROW(OFFSET(A1,COUNTA(A:A)-1,0))`

Then, in another cell, using `INDIRECT`, I used the exact cell ranges in the original formula you provided.